# temporary tables or attributes

Tags: javascript, postgresql, postgis

how do I create and manipulate information temporarily spacial? and codify so as not to overwrite and to be used in a web application.

thanks for answers

Comment: ricardo, Can you please expand upon your question?  It's not clear to me what "temporarily spacial," "codify," and "not to overwrite" mean without some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use 2 strategies:

1. Create table with `session_id` column filed which maps to your web application session, it is used for "simple" informations which are general.
   Remove this info when web session is finished or after some time.
2. Create table with name that you know it will be temporary (prefix it with something like `temp_`), then create "master" table with info about which session use such table. When session is destroyed you will have to drop those tables, or drop it after some time. I use this strategy for more specialized cases. In this case you will have to remember "temp" table name in session data.

I do not use true TEMP tables because it will not work with database connection pooling I use.